# Firestore Recyclerview item doesn't update when doing add, update, delete data

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have a problem when doing add, update, and delete with my firestore recyclerview. The problem is my recyclerview item updating automatically when doing add, update, and delete. But when I open my firestore , my data already updating. I already added notifydatasetchange method but still, can't solve my problem. Here is my adapter code

```
public class SMPAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SMPAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private List<SMPModel> smpModelList;
private Fragment fragment;
private FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

public SMPAdapter(List<SMPModel> smpModelList, Fragment fragment) {
    this.smpModelList = smpModelList;
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.smp_item, parent, false);
    firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {
    final SMPModel smpModel = smpModelList.get(position);
    final String logoURL = smpModel.getLogoURL();

    if (logoURL != null) {
        Picasso.get().load(logoURL).placeholder(R.drawable.logo_progress_bar).into(myViewHolder.imageViewLogoItem);
    } else {
        myViewHolder.imageViewLogoItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_tanpa_gambar);
    }
    myViewHolder.textViewNamaSMPItem.setText(smpModel.getNamaSMP());
    myViewHolder.textViewAlamatItem.setText(smpModel.getAlamat());

    myViewHolder.cardViewOptionItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(fragment.getActivity(), myViewHolder.cardViewOptionItem);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.option_menu);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        // Menampilkan menu edit
                        case R.id.optionMenuEdit:
                            // Berpindah ke EditDataActivity dan meneruskan data
                            Intent intentEditData = new Intent(fragment.getActivity(), EditDataActivity.class);
                            intentEditData.putExtra("id", smpModel.getId());
                            intentEditData.putExtra("logoURL", smpModel.getLogoURL());
                            intentEditData.putExtra("namaSMP", smpModel.getNamaSMP());
                            intentEditData.putExtra("alamat", smpModel.getAlamat());
                            intentEditData.putExtra("kecamatan", smpModel.getKecamatan());
                            intentEditData.putExtra("status", smpModel.getStatus());
                            intentEditData.putExtra("latitude", smpModel.getLatitude().toString());
                            intentEditData.putExtra("longitude", smpModel.getLongitude().toString());
                            fragment.startActivity(intentEditData);
                            break;
                        // Menampilkan menu hapus
                        case R.id.optionMenuHapus:
                            // Menampilkan pesan "Yakin ingin menghapus?"
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(fragment.getActivity());
                            builder.setMessage("Yakin ingin menghapus?");
                            builder.setCancelable(true);

                            builder.setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    Toast.makeText(fragment.getActivity(), "Data telah dihapus!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    firebaseFirestore.collection("SMP").document(smpModel.getId()).delete();
                                    if (smpModel.getLogoURL() != null) {
                                        firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(smpModel.getLogoURL()).delete();
                                    }
                                    // Menghapus item pada RecyclerView
                                    smpModelList.remove(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                                    notifyItemRemoved(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                                    notifyItemChanged(myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), smpModelList.size());
                                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                            builder.setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                            alertDialog.show();
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });
}
```

and below is my data_fragment

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    // Memeriksa jumlah data pada variabel smpModelList
    return smpModelList.size();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data, container, false);
    // Inisialisasi variabel
    textViewDataJumlahData = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDataJumlahData);
    searchViewData = view.findViewById(R.id.searchViewData);
    recyclerViewSMP = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewSMP);
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    smpModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    smpAdapter = new SMPAdapter(smpModelArrayList, DataFragment.this);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerViewSMP.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerViewSMP.setAdapter(smpAdapter);

    firebaseFirestore.collection("SMP").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            smpModelArrayList.clear();
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                int size = task.getResult().size();
                String jumlahData = Long.toString(size);
                textViewDataJumlahData.setText(jumlahData);

                for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                        SMPModel smpModel = documentSnapshot.toObject(SMPModel.class);
                        smpModel.setId(documentSnapshot.getId());
                        smpModelArrayList.add(smpModel);
                    }
                smpAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Gagal mengambil data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    if (searchViewData != null) {
        searchViewData.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                ArrayList<SMPModel> searchSMPModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (SMPModel smpModel : smpModelArrayList) {
                    if (smpModel.getNamaSMP().toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())) {
                        searchSMPModelArrayList.add(smpModel);
                    }
                }
                SMPAdapter smpAdapter = new SMPAdapter(searchSMPModelArrayList, DataFragment.this);
                recyclerViewSMP.setAdapter(smpAdapter);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.tambah_data_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menuTambahData) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TambahDataActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        searchViewData.clearFocus();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what the problem is. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: No, i dont have any error in my log cat. My problem is, my recyclerview item doesnt added automaticlly when i added data from another activity, and that also happened when i doing update (the item doesnt change) and delete (the item doesnt remove) until i refresh the fragment. Sorry for my bad english sir @AlexMamo